# Gradle 3.0.1 Unable to find a matching configuration

Tags: java, android, gradle

I have added a library project which is previously working but after upgrading android studio 3.0,gradle 3.0.1 it gives me error[image].

i have searched a lot of places and every solution is like use same build types,i have already done that ,bt same error occurs,i am adding my gradle files,

app.gradle file[image]

[image]

library.gradle

Comment: ARE YOU SURE YOU UPDATED TO `3.0.1` not `3.1.0` ?? (coz thats the latest version)

Comment: yes i am sure.                                                                               classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.0.1'